# How to handle a QDialog displayed out of screen?

Tags: qt, qmainwindow, qdialog, qtgui

I have a main widow. I move it to an bottom edge or corner. Then I open a dialog by click some button in it. The dialog is positioned at the center of the main window since I set the main window as its parent. However, the dialog is not displayed on the screen because the main window is at the edge or corner. How to make it displayed on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `move` it with negative coordinates until it becomes on screen:

```
dialog.move(-dialog.width(), -dialog.height())
```

This should move it so it's bottom right edge aligns with main windows's top left edge.

Or you could make the dialog parentless and move it in relation to screen coordinates instead:

```
dialog.setParent(None)
dialog.move(400, 300)
```

Comment: Do you know how to check if it is out of screen?

Comment: @user1899020: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtwidgets/qwidget.html#visible-prop but you can always ask the position and compare with the screen coordinates, if the former does not work out.

Comment: @user1899020: That probably should be another question. But that depends on the widget has a parent or not.